# Updating entity framework model using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a problem with updating data in an entity framework model. I have a few tables in the model (`Users`, `UserActivity` and `Orders`). I have added associations between the tables, one between `Users` and `UserActivity` and one between `Users` and `Orders`. The associations are through the column `UserID`. These two associations have inserted into my Users table two virtual column:

```
public virtual UserActivity UserActivity { get; set; }

public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
```

The problem is following: when I write code to update table Users

```
var context1 = new Entities1();

var chechUser = (from c in context1.Users
                 where c.Username == LabelUsername.Text
                 select c).Single();

chechUser.Name = TextBoxNewName.Text;
context1.SaveChanges();
```

When I try to update Entity the following error shows up:

> Invalid column name 'UserActivity_UserID'.
>   Invalid column name 'Orders_UserId'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'UserActivity_UserID'.
>   Invalid column name 'Orders_UserId'.

Could someone tell me what to do?

Thank you all for help. I have solved my problem by adding these two columns to the SQL DB. Now it's work fine.

Comment: You should really include the entities, it's very difficult to diagnose without them.

Comment: Are you sure your db is up-to-date? If you're using migrations, perhaps you should run an Update-Database first.

Comment: Post the SQL Tables if any and post the entire code of models

Comment: What are the column names once you've populated and taken a look at chechUser ? What are the column names in your model?

Comment: I want to post an image of my model but I don't have enough reputation (I need 10, and mine is 9). So I will write the columns: Users has columns-UserID,Name,Surname. UserActivity has columns: - UserID, LogINTimeDate, ChangedNameTimeDate, ChangedSurnameTimeDate, Orders has columns - UserID, FirstOrder, LastOrder.

Comment: Perhaps a trigger or an stored-procedure causes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your SQL server with the following columns: UserActivity_UserID, Orders_UserId.

Or in the code remove this two columns(Map again your DB to the edmx file).

Comment: I tried to remove columns but then the mapping error shows. Could you please explain me how to update SQL server, in more details. I am new in both Entity and SQL. Should I add some columns in SQL database, or just to add some lines of code which will put some values in this virtual columns?

Comment: Open your SQL server -> your DB. find your table there. Right click on your table and then design. Then add this two columns to the table(Just add two columns with the specific name and the required type). Then try again to run your code.